# how to parse Json object having no TAG

Tags: json, tags

I have a problem in parsing Json Object, here is my json result. i am confuse that how to parse this json, because in this result no tag found.
"most_read_pages": [
    1,
    2,
    4,
    5,
    6
  ]

Comment: I think this is not valid... Check http://jsonlint.org/ to see if your json string is valid

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like:

```
var jsonData = { "most_read_pages": [ 1, 2, 10, 30, 55 ] };
```

Then you can access each entry with `jsonData.most_read_pages[index]` where `index` is 0 to 4.

E.g. to access the 5th element in the array (55), you can do:

```js
var jsonData = { "most_read_pages": [ 1, 2, 10, 30, 55 ] };

alert(jsonData.most_read_pages[4]);
```